# How to change progress bar's progress color in Android

Tags: android, material-design, android-progressbar, progress-indicator

I'm using an horizontal progress bar in my Android application, and I want to change its progress color (which is Yellow by default). How can I do it using `code` (not XML)?

Comment: Have you tried MyProgressBar.setProgressDrawable(Drawable d) specifying a bitmap with the color you want? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#setProgressDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html

Comment: Yes i've tried it but it doesn't work. It sets the background color of the whole progress bar view instead of setting the background color of only the bar itself.

Thanks.

Comment: `android:indeterminateTint="@android:color/white"` works only on API >=21

Comment: `android:progressTint="@android:color/white"` when you use non-indeterminate

Answer (score 316, accepted):

I'm sorry that it's not the answer, but what's driving the requirement setting it from code ?
And `.setProgressDrawable` should work if it's defined correctly

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="5dip" />
        <gradient
                android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d"
                android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#ff747674"
                android:angle="270"
        />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="#80ffd300"
                    android:centerColor="#80ffb600"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#a0ffcb00"
                    android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners
                android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/progress_start"
                android:endColor="@color/progress_end"
                android:angle="270" 
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: The reason is because I'm creating the progress bar dynamically, and setting its color upon user request. Since I usually use code for building my GUI screen and components, I'm not familiar with the attached XML and I don't know what's a layer-list (although I'm guessing that you are building the progress bar based on several layers..).

In case I do want to use the XML you've attached - where should I place the it in the project's folder and is there anything more I need to do for creating a progress bar based on the XML settings ?

Thanks.

Comment: You save this xml as a file and put it in the drawable folder ( let's say my_progress.xml ) than you set it as a drawable in
MyProgressBar.setProgressDrawable()
To change colors - you'll need to change those values in @color/progress_start
@color/progress_end 
It's basically a gradient and you can put hex in there.

Comment: Note - file is  the copy of the one that's in SDK. I've dropped copyright here. If you look in the res/drawable folder you'll see exactly what i've posted - colors are set to the yellow gradient, instead of custom colors.

Comment: Its does not show any color change to me. please tell the color which worked out.

Comment: Hi Alex , your answers is very nice. but, i am tried to change custom progress wheel color at runtime. but, i could not. please help me to solve my issue.. after progress reaches100%, then that time change the color and start progress..i download code from this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503718/color-changing-in-custom-progress-wheel-at-runtime-in-android-programmatically

Comment: can we adjust background width of seekbar ?

Comment: Just put these all in a `<layer-list>` and this works perfect

Comment: If we would like to perform operations on click of  each color of a progress bar. what we can do?

Comment: @AlexVolovoy I know it's been a while but could you add the folder where you took the file from? Was it this one `%SDK-FOLDER%/platforms/android-*/data/res/drawable/progress_horizontal.xml`

Comment: If you want round `progressIndicators` as well just change `<clip>` to `<scale android:scaleWidth="100%">` Enjoy!

Comment: Hi, I think Alex' solution is correct answer. I checked https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-change-the-progressbar-color-in-android/ and see same solution. I used it.

Answer (score 552):

This is not programmatically but I think it could help a lot of people anyway.
I tried a lot and the most efficient way was to add this lines to my ProgressBar in the .xml File:

```
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"
            android:indeterminateTint="@color/secondary"
```

So in the end this code did it for me:

```
<ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"
            android:indeterminateTint="@color/secondary">
```

This solution works for **API 21+**

Comment: There are also setter methods for these properties which can be called if dynamic color must be set.

Comment: Do I have to make a custom resource file for api 21+ and api <= 20? Or are those attributes just ignored in api <= 20?

Comment: @shriduttkothari how can it be the best?... it from 21+

Comment: It is a good answer, just use @TargetApi anotation in the method that change the color so when it is less API 21 it doesn't crash

Answer (score 540):

For a horizontal ProgressBar, you can use a `ColorFilter`, too, like this:

```
progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(
    Color.RED, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

[image: Red ProgressBar using color filter]

**Note:** This modifies the appearance of all progress bars in your app. To only modify one specific progress bar, do this:

```
Drawable progressDrawable = progressBar.getProgressDrawable().mutate();
progressDrawable.setColorFilter(Color.RED, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
progressBar.setProgressDrawable(progressDrawable);
```

If progressBar is indeterminate then use `getIndeterminateDrawable()` instead of `getProgressDrawable()`.

Since Lollipop (API 21) you can set a progress tint:

```
progressBar.setProgressTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED));
```

[image: Red ProgressBar using progress tint]

Comment: I wanted to use this answer as it seemed to me to be the simplest one but my progress bar is completely red independently of the progress value. Are you sure of the Mode to use?

Comment: I justed tested it again, here it works perfectly. Did you set a progress? Maybe you only see the light red background.

Comment: Yes I set a progress, I had to set a color with transparency for this to work. I tested it on android 2.2, not sure if it could have an influence.

Comment: @resus I have the same problem, the bar was fully red and no progress was visible. But I solved it changing Mode.SRC_IN to Mode.MULTIPLY.

Comment: Don't forget to do the same for `getIndeterminateDrawable` if you are using indeterminate progress.

Comment: Also note that doing this will modify drawables of ALL progress bars in your app. To do this only to a particular one, call mutate() on drawable, then set color filter on it and then call set*Drawable on your progressBar.

Comment: how to don't change background color ? I just want to change progress color.

Comment: That's pretty neat. How to change RED to another custom color like #12ddfe

Comment: You can use Color.parseColor("#12ddfe") instead of Color.RED.

Comment: Great it work onward 2.3 For  indeterminate progress bar  i am using **getIndeterminateDrawable**

Comment: Awesome suggestion! `progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED, Mode.SRC_IN);` works for me without modification. And with mode `MULTIPLY` progress drawable turns a couple of shades darker.

Comment: for a circle one?

Comment: @TorbenKohlmeier Since this is the most popular answer, I think it would be very helpful if you added "@dimsuz"s warning that this will modify drawables of all progress bars and one should use mutate to prevent that.

Comment: Not that you must call `setProgress()` **after** setting the tint, otherwise you only get an empty progress bar. At least this is true on Android 4.4.4.

Comment: All what I need, I only added `Color.parseColor(myColor)` to use a color from a `String` stored on database

Comment: the method `setColorFilter` is deprecated from API 29. To resolve follow this link [https://stackoverflow.com/a/56717316/3122668](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56717316/3122668) as suggest @shmakova

Answer (score 246):

For my indeterminate progressbar (spinner) I just set a color filter on the drawable. Works great and just one line.

Example where setting color to red:

```
ProgressBar spinner = new android.widget.ProgressBar(
                context,
                null,
                android.R.attr.progressBarStyle);

spinner.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

[image]

Comment: I like your answer the best.  For mine to work though I had to do this: myProgressBarSpinner.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFF000000, foregroundColorDesired));

Comment: Also note that doing this will modify drawables of ALL progress bars in your app. To do this only to a particular one, call mutate() on drawable, then set color filter on it and then call setIntederminateDrawable on your progressBar.

Comment: NB: Those who use this and wondering why their colour doesn't look exactly as the hex string they put in, it has a Multiple Colour filter on it. Change `android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY` to `PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN` and you will get the exact hex colour.

Comment: I think he just need this answer ..... 
android:indeterminateTint="@android:color/black"

Comment: i used as : progressBar= (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this,android.R.color.white), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

Answer (score 219):

This is an old question, but using theme is not mentioned here. If your default theme is using `AppCompat`, your `ProgressBar`'s color will be `colorAccent` you have defined.

Changing `colorAccent` will also change your `ProgressBar`'s color, but there changes also reflects at multiple places. So, if you want a different color just for a specific `PregressBar` you can do that by applying theme to that `ProgressBar` :

- Extend your default theme and override `colorAccent`

  ```
  <style name="AppTheme.WhiteAccent">
      <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item> <!-- Whatever color you want-->
  </style>
  ```
- And in `ProgressBar` add the `android:theme` attribute:

  ```
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WhiteAccent"
  ```

So it will look something like this:

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WhiteAccent" />
```

So you are just changing a `colorAccent` for your particular `ProgressBar`.

**Note**: Using `style` will not work. You need to use `android:theme` only.
You can find more use of theme here: https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/JXHKyhsWHAH

Comment: finally! thanks, it seems like not many developers use AppCompat, many users just vote-ups answers with solution for API 21+, not good at all, they should support more devices/OS as possible

Comment: Awesome! Worked for me, but I had to make sure there was a parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat" somewhere up the style hierarchy I had another parent and it didn't work at first.

Comment: @Nublodeveloper Yes I mentioned that in the first line if you have noticed.

Comment: @kirtan403 Ah, yes, I get it now you mention it, but I didn't understand it that way when I first read it. I read it too fast and I was looking for code. Thanks anyway, your answer is the best for me!

Comment: +1 Liked your solution. But how to set the color of the theme in java??? For example if I want it to be red <color name="red">#ff5900</color>

Comment: @kirtan403 is there any way to change 'colorAccent' of ProgressBar value programetically?

Comment: how to horizantal progressbar?

Comment: Am i wrong, or does this too work only for API 21+ ?

Comment: Thanks, buddy! This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 69):

**All API**

if use all API just create the theme in style

style.xml

```
<resources>

    //...

    <style name="progressBarBlue" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

and use in progress

```
<ProgressBar
    ...
    android:theme="@style/progressBarBlue" />
```

---

**API level 21 and higher**

if used in API level 21 and higher just use this code:

```
<ProgressBar
   //...
   android:indeterminate="true"
   android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"
   android:indeterminateTint="@color/secondary"/>
```

Comment: Nice , i think style.xml method is best .(no need above 20 api)

Answer (score 53):

This works for me. It also works for lower version too. Add this to your syles.xml

```
<style name="ProgressBarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

And use it like this in xml

```
<ProgressBar
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:theme="@style/ProgressBarTheme"
   />
```

Comment: I've implemented this in the [CryptoTweets](https://github.com/AdamSHurwitz/CryptoTweets) sample app. I've found the parent theme is not required for this solution to work as expected. `parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"`

Comment: Simplest solution if you want to tint the default progressbar. Thanks

Comment: @Saul_programa Glad to know , that it helps you

Answer (score 41):

This worked for me :

```
<ProgressBar
 android:indeterminateTint="#d60909"
 ... />
```

Comment: Only used in API level 21 and higher

Answer (score 35):

as per some of the suggestions, you CAN specify a shape and clipdrawable with a colour, then set it.  I have this working programatically.  This is how I do it..

First make sure you import the drawable library..

`import android.graphics.drawable.*;`

Then use the code similar to below;

```
ProgressBar pg = (ProgressBar)row.findViewById(R.id.progress);
final float[] roundedCorners = new float[] { 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };
pgDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RoundRectShape(roundedCorners, null,null));
String MyColor = "#FF00FF";
pgDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor(MyColor));
ClipDrawable progress = new ClipDrawable(pgDrawable, Gravity.LEFT, ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);
pg.setProgressDrawable(progress);   
pg.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.progress_horizontal));
pg.setProgress(45);
```

Comment: I tried the code above, unfortunately it just results in an "empty" progress bar. Am I missing something?

Comment: You need to call setLevel on the ClipDrawable. It takes a value from 0 to 10000. So, progress.setLevel(2500) would be 25% full.

Comment: I have submitted an edit to the answer that explains one reason for an "empty" progress bar - and 2 ways to fix it (incl @HappyEngineer's fix)

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier can you post the explanation + 2 ways in the comment section? `progress.setLevel(2500)` doesn't work for me and apparently your edit wasn't accepted for some reason. Thanks. +1.

Comment: @ateiob I have written [a new answer to explain...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11288434/383414)

Comment: In order to replace deprecated methods in the last line: pg.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), android.R.drawable.progress_horizontal));

Answer (score 31):

if Indeterminate:

```
((ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar))
    .getIndeterminateDrawable()
    .setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Comment: I used this, but it doesn't animate, just color has been applied... I'm using circular progressbar

Answer (score 29):

Trust me, the easiest solution is just paste this inside progressBar :

```
android:indeterminateTint="@android:color/white"
```

Answer (score 25):

Nowadays in 2016 I found some pre-Lollipop devices don't honour the `colorAccent` setting, so my final solution for all APIs is now the following:

```
// fixes pre-Lollipop progressBar indeterminateDrawable tinting
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

    Drawable wrapDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(mProgressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable());
    DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapDrawable, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.holo_green_light));
    mProgressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(DrawableCompat.unwrap(wrapDrawable));
} else {
    mProgressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.holo_green_light), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
}
```

For bonus points, it doesn't use any deprecated code. Try it!

Comment: Don't forget to call `wrapDrawable.mutate()` with `DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapDrawable.mutate(), ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.holo_green_light));`

Comment: Just tried it (again) on a fresh new 4.4.2 emulator and it works without any issues whatsoever, check your `.xml` settings and also if something else is overriding the `ProgressBar`color.

Answer (score 25):

```xml
android:progressTint="#ffffff"
```

Answer (score 25):

For SDK ver 21 and above

```
android:indeterminateTint="@color/orange"
```

in XML Works for me, is easy enough.

Comment: If you want to change for the whole app, kindly change the value of                   <color name="RedAccent">#FE6C27</color>.    in your Values/colors.xml.

Answer (score 24):

### THis is what i did. Worked.

**ProgressBar:**

```
<ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progressdrawable"
           />
```

---

**progressdrawable.xml:**
*Here use gradient to change colour as you like. And android:toDegrees="X" increse the value of X and progressbar rotate fast. Decrease and it rotate slow.Customize according to your needs.*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:duration="4000"
            android:fromDegrees="0"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="360" >

            <shape
                android:innerRadius="20dp"
                android:shape="ring"
                android:thickness="4dp"
                android:useLevel="false" >
                <size
                    android:height="48dp"
                    android:width="48dp" />

                <gradient
                    android:centerColor="#80ec7e2a"
                    android:centerY="0.5"
                    android:endColor="#ffec7e2a"
                    android:startColor="#00ec7e2a"
                    android:type="sweep"
                    android:useLevel="false" />
            </shape>

        </rotate>
```

---

**sample:**
[image]

Comment: @Ixx when it runs , it looks good. You can anyways change colour's !!

Answer (score 24):

Add in ProgressBar inside of Xml

For SDK ver 21 and above

```
android:indeterminateTint="@color/red"
```

Comment: He specifically asked to do it "in code" which means in Java, not XML. Unless he added that later after you had already answered.

Comment: Yes, this has already happened, but is there a problem you are facing, I can help you :)

Answer (score 20):

Hit the same problem while working on modifying the look/feel of the default progress bar. Here is some more info that will hopefully help people :)

- The name of the xml file must only contain characters: `a-z0-9_.` (ie. no capitals!)
- To reference your "drawable" it is `R.drawable.filename`
- To override the default look, you use `myProgressBar.setProgressDrawable(...)`, however you need can't just refer to your custom layout as `R.drawable.filename`, you need to retrieve it as a `Drawable`:

  ```
  Resources res = getResources();
  myProgressBar.setProgressDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.filename);
  ```
- You need to set style before setting progress/secondary progress/max *(setting it afterwards for me resulted in an 'empty' progress bar)*

Answer (score 19):

You can try to change your Styles, Themes, or using android:indeterminateTint="@color/yourColor" anywhere you want, but there's just one way o doing that will work on any Android SKD version:

If you progress bar is not indeterminate, please use:

```
progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.yourColor), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN );
```

If you progress bar is indeterminate, please use:

```
progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.yourColor), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN );
```

It's sad that Android is such a mess!

Comment: Thanks! It works for indeterminate `ProgressBar`, but for determinate it paints whole scale with color.

Answer (score 18):

For default (  **indeterminate**  )

add

```
android:indeterminateTint="@color/white"
```

for **determinate**

```
    android:progressTint="@color/color_1"

    //OR
    progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter( PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.RED,android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
```

Answer (score 16):

How I did it in horizontal ProgressBar:

```
    LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) progressBar.getProgressDrawable();
    Drawable progressDrawable = layerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.progress);
    progressDrawable.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Comment: I did the same thing, plus the background color change: layerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.background).setColorFilter(trackColor,PorterDuff.Mode.SRC);

Comment: This answer along with @KamenDobrev 's comment is the only one that actually did what I wanted. When I only set a color filter to the progress drawable the background color changed as well.

Answer (score 15):

There's probably one thing that hasn't been referred to in this answer:

If your theme is inheriting from `Theme.AppCompat`, `ProgressBar` will assume the color you defined as `"colorAccent"` in your theme.

So, using..

> `<item name="colorAccent">@color/custom_color</item>`

..will tint the color of the ProgressBar automagically to the `@color/custom_color` .

Comment: I needed to use <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/highlight</item>

Answer (score 15):

Simplest Solution if you want to change the colour in the layout xml file, use the below code and use **indeterminateTint** property for your desired color.

```
    <ProgressBar
      android:id="@+id/progressBar"
      style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:indeterminate="true"
      android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"
      android:indeterminateTint="#ddbd4e"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Answer (score 14):

The most simple way of changing the foreground and background colour of a progress bar is

```
<ProgressBar
                        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                        android:id="@+id/pb_main"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="8dp"
                        android:progress="30"
                        android:progressTint="#82e9de"
                        android:progressBackgroundTint="#82e9de"
                        />
```

just add

```
                        android:progressTint="#82e9de" //for foreground colour
                        android:progressBackgroundTint="#82e9de" //for background colour
```

Comment: You should indicate that this is working only for android API > 21

Answer (score 13):

This solution worked for me :

```
<style name="Progressbar.White" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
</style>

<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="@dimen/d_40"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/d_40"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:theme="@style/Progressbar.White"/>
```

Answer (score 10):

To change horizontal ProgressBar color (in kotlin):

```
fun tintHorizontalProgress(progress: ProgressBar, @ColorInt color: Int = ContextCompat.getColor(progress.context, R.color.colorPrimary)){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        progress.progressTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(color)
    } else{
        val layerDrawable = progress.progressDrawable as? LayerDrawable
        val progressDrawable = layerDrawable?.findDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.progress)
        progressDrawable?.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
    }
}
```

To change indeterminate ProgressBar color:

```
fun tintIndeterminateProgress(progress: ProgressBar, @ColorInt color: Int = ContextCompat.getColor(progress.context, R.color.colorPrimary)){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        progress.indeterminateTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(color)
    } else {
        (progress.indeterminateDrawable as? LayerDrawable)?.apply {
            if (numberOfLayers >= 2) {
                setId(0, android.R.id.progress)
                setId(1, android.R.id.secondaryProgress)
                val progressDrawable = findDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.progress).mutate()
                progressDrawable.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it finally normally tint pre-lollipop progressBars

[image: tinted progress on api 19]

Answer (score 10):

Simply use:

```
DrawableCompat.setTint(progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable(),yourColor)
```

Comment: This is really simple and seems to work fine! Thank you

Answer (score 9):

One more little thing, the theme solution does work if you inherit a base theme, so for app compact your theme should be:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Custom" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/custom</item>
</style>
```

And then set this in the progress bar theme

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressCircle_progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Custom"
    android:indeterminate="true"/>
```

Answer (score 8):

simply use:

```
PorterDuff.Mode mode = PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1) {
    mode = PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY;
}

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    progressBar.setProgressTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED));
    progressBar.setProgressBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED));
} else {
    Drawable progressDrawable;
    progressDrawable = (progressBar.isIndeterminate() ? progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable() : progressBar.getProgressDrawable()).mutate();
    progressDrawable.setColorFilter(context.getResources().getColor(Color.RED), mode);
    progressBar.setProgressDrawable(progressDrawable);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Horizontal progress bar custom material style :**

To change color of background and progress of horizontal progress bar.

```
<style name="MyProgressBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressBackgroundTint">#69f0ae</item>
    <item name="android:progressTint">#b71c1c</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">200dp</item>
</style>
```

Apply it to progress bar by setting style attribute, for custom material styles and custom progress bar check http://www.zoftino.com/android-progressbar-and-custom-progressbar-examples

Comment: this requires minimum api level 21

Answer (score 7):

Use the [android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat.html):

```
            Drawable progressDrawable = progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable();
            if (progressDrawable  != null) {
                Drawable mutateDrawable = progressDrawable.mutate();
                DrawableCompat.setTint(mutateDrawable, primaryColor);
                progressBar.setProgressDrawable(mutateDrawable);
            }
```

Answer (score 6):

Posted to add info about [PaulieG's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5209762/383414), since ateiob asked me to explain something...

---

I can say that there is (or at least was, at the time of writing when I looked at that current version of Android source code) a bug/issue/optimisation in the `ProgressBar` code that ignores an attempt to set the progress to a value it is already at.

- i.e. if progress = 45, and you try to set it to 45, the code will do nothing, and **will not redraw the progress**.

After calling `ProgressBar.setProgressDrawable()`, your progress bar will be blank (because you changed the drawable part).

This means you need to set the progress, and redraw it. But if you just set the progress to a preserved value, it will do nothing.

You must set it to 0 first, then to the "old" value again, and the bar will redraw.

---

So to summarise:

- preserve the "old" progress value
- update the drawable / colour (makes bar blank)
- reset the progress to 0 (otherwise next line does nothing)
- reset the progress to the "old" value (fixes bar)
- invalidate

---

Below is a method I have that does this:

```
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    progBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_base);

    int oldProgress = progBar.getProgress();

    // define new drawable/colour
    final float[] roundedCorners = new float[]
        { 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };
    ShapeDrawable shape = new ShapeDrawable(new RoundRectShape(
        roundedCorners, null, null));
    String MyColor = "#FF00FF";
    shape.getPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor(MyColor));
    ClipDrawable clip = new ClipDrawable(shape, Gravity.LEFT,
        ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);
    progBar.setProgressDrawable(clip);

    progBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
        android.R.drawable.progress_horizontal));

    // work around: setProgress() ignores a change to the same value
    progBar.setProgress(0);
    progBar.setProgress(oldProgress);

    progBar.invalidate();
}
```

---

As far as HappyEngineer's solution, I think it was a similar workaround, to manually set the "progress" offset. In either case, the above code should work for you.

Comment: Thanks..this works indeed..but as my drawable was static (from resources)..it didn't work. It only worked after i added  "drawable.invalidateSelf();" before the 'setProgress(0)' and 'setProgressDrawable(drawable)'

Answer (score 5):

If any one want to change color programmatically:

```
progressBar.progressTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED)
```

Answer (score 4):

For a horizontal style ProgressBar I use:

```
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.ClipDrawable;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable;

public void setColours(ProgressBar progressBar,
                        int bgCol1, int bgCol2, 
                        int fg1Col1, int fg1Col2, int value1,
                        int fg2Col1, int fg2Col2, int value2)
  {
    //If solid colours are required for an element, then set
    //that elements Col1 param s the same as its Col2 param
    //(eg fg1Col1 == fg1Col2).

    //fgGradDirection and/or bgGradDirection could be parameters
    //if you require other gradient directions eg LEFT_RIGHT.

    GradientDrawable.Orientation fgGradDirection
        = GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM;
    GradientDrawable.Orientation bgGradDirection
        = GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM;

    //Background
    GradientDrawable bgGradDrawable = new GradientDrawable(
            bgGradDirection, new int[]{bgCol1, bgCol2});
    bgGradDrawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    bgGradDrawable.setCornerRadius(5);
    ClipDrawable bgclip = new ClipDrawable(
            bgGradDrawable, Gravity.LEFT, ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);     
    bgclip.setLevel(10000);

    //SecondaryProgress
    GradientDrawable fg2GradDrawable = new GradientDrawable(
            fgGradDirection, new int[]{fg2Col1, fg2Col2});
    fg2GradDrawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    fg2GradDrawable.setCornerRadius(5);
    ClipDrawable fg2clip = new ClipDrawable(
            fg2GradDrawable, Gravity.LEFT, ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);        

    //Progress
    GradientDrawable fg1GradDrawable = new GradientDrawable(
            fgGradDirection, new int[]{fg1Col1, fg1Col2});
    fg1GradDrawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    fg1GradDrawable.setCornerRadius(5);
    ClipDrawable fg1clip = new ClipDrawable(
            fg1GradDrawable, Gravity.LEFT, ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);        

    //Setup LayerDrawable and assign to progressBar
    Drawable[] progressDrawables = {bgclip, fg2clip, fg1clip};
    LayerDrawable progressLayerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(progressDrawables);     
    progressLayerDrawable.setId(0, android.R.id.background);
    progressLayerDrawable.setId(1, android.R.id.secondaryProgress);
    progressLayerDrawable.setId(2, android.R.id.progress);

    //Copy the existing ProgressDrawable bounds to the new one.
    Rect bounds = progressBar.getProgressDrawable().getBounds();
    progressBar.setProgressDrawable(progressLayerDrawable);     
    progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setBounds(bounds);

    // setProgress() ignores a change to the same value, so:
    if (value1 == 0)
        progressBar.setProgress(1);
    else
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
    progressBar.setProgress(value1);

    // setSecondaryProgress() ignores a change to the same value, so:
    if (value2 == 0)
        progressBar.setSecondaryProgress(1);
    else
        progressBar.setSecondaryProgress(0);
    progressBar.setSecondaryProgress(value2);

    //now force a redraw
    progressBar.invalidate();
  }
```

An example call would be:

```
  setColours(myProgressBar, 
          0xff303030,   //bgCol1  grey 
          0xff909090,   //bgCol2  lighter grey 
          0xff0000FF,   //fg1Col1 blue 
          0xffFFFFFF,   //fg1Col2 white
          50,           //value1
          0xffFF0000,   //fg2Col1 red 
          0xffFFFFFF,   //fg2Col2 white
          75);          //value2
```

If you don't need the 'secondary progress' simply set value2 to value1.

Answer (score 4):

Apply this custom style to the progress bar.

```
<style name="customProgress" parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small">
        <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/progress</item>
        <item name="android:duration">40</item>
        <item name="android:animationCache">true</item>
        <item name="android:drawingCacheQuality">low</item>
        <item name="android:persistentDrawingCache">animation</item>
    </style>
```

@drawable/progress.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_white"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%" />
```

Use this type of image for progress bar.
[image]

For better result you can use multiple progress images. And please don't hesitate using images, because Android Platform itself use images for progressbar.
The code is extracted from sdk :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code for changing the color of ProgressBar by programatically.

```
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb_listProgressBar);
int colorCodeDark = Color.parseColor("#F44336");
progressBar.setIndeterminateTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(colorCodeDark));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ProgressBar freeRamPb = findViewById(R.id.free_ram_progress_bar);

freeRamPb.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(
Color.BLUE, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Comment: Awesome. Quick and effective solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
ProgressBar bar;

private Handler progressBarHandler = new Handler();

GradientDrawable progressGradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable(
        GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT, new int[]{
                0xff1e90ff,0xff006ab6,0xff367ba8});
ClipDrawable progressClipDrawable = new ClipDrawable(
        progressGradientDrawable, Gravity.LEFT, ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);
Drawable[] progressDrawables = {
        new ColorDrawable(0xffffffff),
        progressClipDrawable, progressClipDrawable};
LayerDrawable progressLayerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(progressDrawables);


int status = 0;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setContentView(R.layout.startup);

    bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.start_page_progressBar);
    bar.setProgress(0);
    bar.setMax(100);

    progressLayerDrawable.setId(0, android.R.id.background);
    progressLayerDrawable.setId(1, android.R.id.secondaryProgress);
    progressLayerDrawable.setId(2, android.R.id.progress);

    bar.setProgressDrawable(progressLayerDrawable);
}
```

This helped me to set a custom color to progressbar through code. Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

It is so simple using attr , if you are dealing with multistyle apps:

try this way:

Declare below attribute attrs.xml

```
 <attr name="circularProgressTheme" format="reference"></attr>
```

Paste below code in styles.xml

```
 <style name="ProgressThemeWhite" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF0000</item>
    </style>

    <style name="circularProgressThemeWhite">
        <item name="android:theme">@style/ProgressThemeWhite</item>
    </style>


  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

   <item name="circularProgressTheme">@style/circularProgressThemeWhite</item>

 </style>
```

use progress bar like below

```
  <ProgressBar
        style="?attr/circularProgressTheme"
        android:id="@+id/commonProgress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

`Horizontal ProgressBar` uses `rectangle shape` drawable for background, `ClipDrawable` constructed from `rectangle shape` for progresses (primary & secondary). Tinting changes colors to some tint. **If you want targeted colors** for all three separately then you can use `ProgressBar.setProgressDrawable()` as following:

```
    LayerDrawable progressBarDrawable = new LayerDrawable(
        new Drawable[]{
                new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
                            new int[]{Color.parseColor("#ff0000ff"),Color.parseColor("#ff0000ff")}),

                new ClipDrawable(
                            new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
                                    new int[]{Color.parseColor("#ff00ff00"),Color.parseColor("#ff00ff00")}),
                            Gravity.START,
                            ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL),

                new ClipDrawable(
                        new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
                                new int[]{Color.parseColor("#ffff0000"),Color.parseColor("#ffff0000")}),
                        Gravity.START,
                        ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL)
            });

    progressBarDrawable.setId(0,android.R.id.background);
    progressBarDrawable.setId(1,android.R.id.secondaryProgress);
    progressBarDrawable.setId(2,android.R.id.progress);
    ((ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar)).setProgressDrawable(progressBarDrawable);
```

Note that order of drawable layers is important while initializing `LayerDrawable`. First drawable should be for background. As per my experiment switching ids does not work. If you set padding to `progressbar` then this approach will not work. If you need padding then you can use a container for the progressbar such as a `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 2):

Since method `public void setColorFilter(@ColorInt int color, @NonNull PorterDuff.Mode mode)` is deprecated, I use such form:

```
progressBar.indeterminateDrawable.colorFilter =
            PorterDuffColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.black), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that an indeterminate *linear* progress indicator can be made multicolor in newer versions of [material design library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases).

Making animation type of the progress bar `contiguous` achieves this.

- In the layout with this attribute:

  ```
  app:indeterminateAnimationType
  ```
- or programmatically with this method:

  ```
  setIndeterminateAnimationType()
  ```

Refer [here](https://material.io/components/progress-indicators/android#types) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late but this is the easiest solution if you only want to change the color of your progress bar, In your theme, simply add,

@color/your_color

colorSecondary will change you progress color throughout.