# How to change the color of an indefinite ProgressBar?

Tags: android, layout, progress-bar

I have a progressbar with the following style: `style="?android:attr/android:progressBarStyleSmall"`

Sadly the bar is nearly white and in my case displayed on a white background.
The progressbar is nearly invisible because of that.

How can I change the color of the progressbar? A darker grey would be great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason why the bar is of that color is because of the style you have selected. That is a fixed style and uses the system themes for the generation of UI elements.

Look at the source code from [here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/res/res/values/themes.xml&q=progressBarStyleSmall&d=3). This progressBarStyleSmall attribute uses the styles defined [here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/res/res/values/styles.xml&q=progressBarStyleSmall&d=3).

```
<style name="Widget.ProgressBar.Small">
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@android:drawable/progress_small_white</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxWidth">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">16dip</item>
</style>
```

Just create a custom style following the example from the android source code. You would need to replace the android:indeterminateDrawable to what you want.

Answer (score 41):

```
progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(
            getResources().getColor(R.color.light_light_purple),
            android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

**This code changes the default holo inderminate drawable color to your own color.
Define your color code and replace `R.color.light_light_purple` to `R.color.your_color_code`.**

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer. I only recently discovered the color filter method of basically changing anything to whatever color you want, and it's pretty awesome.

Comment: Thanks a lot..!Plzz accept my answer for more benefit to others :)

Comment: I only needed to use this snippet for SDK versions prior to Lollipop, So, I wrapped this snippet in a static method:

`LegacyStyleUtil#adjustLegacyStyle(Context, ProgressBar)`. Then, I invoke this method from my activities/fragments.

`public static void adjustLegacyStyle(Context context, ProgressBar progressBar) {
    if (BuildConfigUtil.isLegacySDK() && progressBar != null) {
    progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(
                    context.getResources().getColor(R.color.green_progress),
                    PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    }
}`

Comment: Does not work on newer Android, where the indeterminate progress bar is simple circle: it stops turning around.

Answer (score 25):

To get a black ProgressBar, use one of the inverse styles:

```
<ProgressBar style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Inverse"/>
<ProgressBar style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large.Inverse"/>
<ProgressBar style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small.Inverse"/>
```

Comment: This doesn't work on one of our Gingerbread models with Cyanogen. Too bad :(

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void setColorOfProgressBar(ProgressBar mProgressBar, int mColor){
    mProgressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(mColor, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a very hard time trying to change it's color. To solve it, I got android's src code and did my own ProgressBar class.

Not the best answer, but it worked for me.

Comment: Can you please share the class?

Answer (score 2):

And the answer was already on SO:

[stackoverflow.com/questions/2020882/how-to-change-progress-bars-progress-color-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020882/how-to-change-progress-bars-progress-color-in-android)

You can simply change the whole drawable that is shown in the progressbar via the `android:indeterminateDrawable` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note, to use

```
<ProgressBar style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Inverse"/>
```

or any of the inverse progress bars, you have to set your minimum android sdk requirement to level 4 (Android 1.6).