# Change style of Indeterminate Progress Bar

Tags: android, progress-bar

I want to change what I have now and is hardly visible:
[image]
to this:
[image]

It's a customized progress Dialog without text, title nor background. Only the spinner.

I used this implementation for a progress Dialog:

```
public class IndeterminateProgressSpinner extends Dialog {
static Dialog dialog;

public static IndeterminateProgressSpinner show(Context context,
        OnCancelListener cancelListener) {
    dialog = new IndeterminateProgressSpinner(context);
    dialog.setTitle(null);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setOnCancelListener(cancelListener);
    /* The next line will add the ProgressBar to the dialog. */
    ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(context);
    dialog.addContentView(pb, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    dialog.show();
    return (IndeterminateProgressSpinner) dialog;
}

public IndeterminateProgressSpinner(Context context) {
    super(context, R.style.indeterminateProgressSpinner);
}
```

And this is the style `R.style.indeterminateProgressSpinner`

```
    <style name="indeterminateProgressSpinner">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">true</item>
    </style>
```

thank you

Comment: So what is your problem? You have some code. What is not working if you are using this code?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729180/how-to-change-the-color-of-an-indefinite-progressbar) will help you

Comment: @Janusz I want to change the progress bar. I don't know how. I don't know how that style works...