# how to change ProgressBar color?

Tags: android, progress

i want to change `Horizontal` `ProgressBar` color

i have tried this

[How to change the color of an indefinite ProgressBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729180/how-to-change-the-color-of-an-indefinite-progressbar)

its not working still progress run in blue color

this is my code

```
<ProgressBar
                 android:id="@+id/mini_progress"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                 android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                 style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="20dip"
                 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                 android:indeterminate="false"
                 android:indeterminateBehavior="repeat"
                 android:indeterminateOnly="true"
                 android:visibility="gone"/>
```

how i can change the color to Pink ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dip" />

                <solid android:color="#f58233" />
            </shape>
        </clip>

        <color android:color="#f58233" />
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dip" />

                <solid android:color="#f58233" />
            </shape>
        </clip>

        <color android:color="#f58233" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Progress Bar -

```
<ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="3dip"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar" />
```

Change color codes according to your need

Comment: Which one to change for background and foreground color ?

Comment: Secondary Progress is for bg color, and progress for foreground color, I guess. Dont exactly remember.

Comment: Initially the progress bar is not visible at all. When I added <item android:id="@android:id/background"> its visible. I think secondaryprogress is not the bg!

Comment: How do you change colour of progress bar when its completely filled?

Answer (score 14):

I did this to get the required color :

```
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"
    android:indeterminateTint="@color/myColor"
```

Works perfectly for me.(API 21 or higher)

Answer (score 12):

For me this worked well.

[image]

```
<ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/verify_progress"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/verify_phone"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar" </ProgressBar>
```

drawable/progress_bar -

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:id="@android:id/background">
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dip" />
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="@color/Gray"
                    android:centerColor="@color/Gray"
                    android:endColor="@color/Gray"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>


        <item
            android:id="@android:id/progress"
            >
            <clip>
                <shape>
                    <corners
                        android:radius="5dip" />
                    <gradient
                        android:startColor="@color/PrimaryColor"
                        android:endColor="@color/PrimaryColor" />
                </shape>
            </clip>
        </item>

    </layer-list>
```

Comment: Yep.  Works across all android versions.

Answer (score 3):

Since API 21 it's a one liner:

```
<ProgressBar
            ...
            android:progressTint="@color/colorAccent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a renderer:

```
public class CustomProgressBarRenderer :ProgressBarRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ProgressBar> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        Control.ProgressDrawable.SetColorFilter(Color.FromRgb(182, 231, 233).ToAndroid(), Android.Graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn);
        //Control.ProgressTintListColor.FromRgb(182, 231, 233).ToAndroid();
        Control.ProgressTintList = Android.Content.Res.ColorStateList.ValueOf(Color.FromRgb(182, 231, 233).ToAndroid());


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this works on pre-lollipop devices.

```
progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(),R.color.product_status_color), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY)
```

Comment: This will fires a `NullPointerException` as `getProgressDrawable()` is null