# Is it possible to change the color of progress bar ? XAMARIN

Tags: c#, layout, xamarin, progress-bar

The question is in the title, I wonder if it's possible to change the color of the progress bar and if possible , how? I use Xamarin studio with Layout ( .axml not .xaml )

Answer (score 0):

Since you are referring to `.axml` I guess you are talking about an Android project. 
You can change the color of a progress bar in exactly the same way as you would do it in a Java project. 
See this: [how to change ProgressBar color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800290/how-to-change-progressbar-color)