# Set Background Color to progressBar

Tags: android, background, progress-bar

I want to put color to my progress bar, I see that I can change the color of tint, but I want to change the main bar, I have been reading about it but the solutions are old and has many lines, it must be a simply way to do it. Really a drawable??

I want my application available to the largest possible number of devices

Depend of my progress value I want to change color programmatically too.

Comment: Check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800290/how-to-change-progressbar-color Probably the same question

Comment: Not the same question because he wants to do it programmatically as well.

Comment: that's true @RobinDavies

Answer (score 0):

add in the styles.xml file like this

```
<item name="colorAccent">@color/whatevercolor</item>
```

Comment: My actual xml code call this: style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal", how can I add the other style?

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty in making fancy progress bars revolves around the reality of what a progress bar is. It's basically a fancy wrapper for a drawable. And getting  drawable to do what you want is difficult. There's lots of lines of code because getting a drawable to do this is difficult. Tinting of drawables is a relatively new feature (android 5.0), so if you want to use it, you restrict yourself to 5.0+.

You might be better off just writing a complete from-scratch custom view. Override onDraw, draw with canvas rendering calls; invalidate every time you want to update the appearance.

To a large extent, the premises around which the original progress bar were designed no longer apply. Consider Android 1.0, that ran on primitive precursors to modern smart phones with 320x240 displays and just enough RAM to inhale before you ran out of memory; no GPUs; and a CPU that is hard pressed to fill the screen with a solid color let alone render a polygon. Obviously no longer the case.

fwiw, there's enough behavior in most widgets that its normally unwise to mess with them. That doesnt really apply to progressBar.