# Change a ProgressDialog spinner Color

Tags: java, android, android-progressbar

I'm trying to change my `ProgressDialog` Spinner color, I found dozens of tutorials to peform this, but they are from 3 or 4 years ago, doesn't work anymore, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800290/how-to-change-progressbar-color),[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020882/how-to-change-progress-bars-progress-color-in-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729180/how-to-change-the-color-of-an-indefinite-progressbar), not working. I was able to change the color by changing the `colorAccent` on styles byt that would be change a lot of stuffs from my design.

I just have this :

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignUpActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loaging....");
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progressDialog.show();
```

Comment: This library supports colorized progress bars. https://github.com/rahatarmanahmed/CircularProgressView

Comment: the problem is, I need a ProgressDialog not a progress bar

Comment: Pass a style Resource to your constructor;

Comment: A progress dialog contains a progress bar. You can create your own, custom progress dialog