# Thin blue progress bar

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-drawable

I'm trying to create a thin, blue progress bar, similar to this:

[image]

I'm not that good with `Drawables`, but what I have changes the `ProgressBar` to green, but I'm not sure how to make it thin and blue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
     >
      <ProgressBar 
        android:id="@+id/ProgressBar" 
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Drawable**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d"
                    android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#ff747674"
                    android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dip" />
                <gradient
                        android:startColor="#80ffd300"
                        android:centerColor="#80ffb600"
                        android:centerY="0.75"
                        android:endColor="#a0ffcb00"
                        android:angle="270"
                />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
    >
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners
                    android:radius="5dip" />
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="#33FF33"
                    android:endColor="#008000"
                    android:angle="270" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: android:layout_height="xxdp"

Comment: Possbile duplicate with:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950956/changing-progress-bar-color-using-xml-in-android-app?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

The height is defined by the `android:layout_height="wrap_content` attribute. You could set it to 2dp for example, to create a thinner progress bar.

Changing your color will be a bit more difficult, since you are using gradients. So you'll have to change your start & end color to some kind of blue.

**What I am using**

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressbar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0.01dp"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="50"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/myprogressbar"
    android:secondaryProgress="0" />
```

**MyProgressBar.xml** in the drawable folder

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="0dip" />
            <gradient android:startColor="#C0C0C0" android:centerColor="#F8F8FF"
                android:centerY="0.75" android:endColor="#ffffff" android:angle="90" />
            <stroke android:width="0.01dp" android:color="#6B8E23" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="0dip" />
                <gradient android:startColor="#9ACD32" android:endColor="#FFFF00"
                    android:angle="90" />
                <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#6B8E23" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Replace the color codes with your own blue color codes:

> android:startColor="#C0C0C0" android:centerColor="#F8F8FF"
>   android:endColor="#ffffff"