# Android progress bar changing color for mic amplitude

Tags: android, android-layout

currently I'm doing some enhancements for my audio recorder and now I added the amplitude to get the mic input levels and display it for the user to see if the audio is being recorded or not. It's working properly with the `dialog.setProgress();` but since I badly wanted it to be displayed nicely in front of the user I plan to make it change in color and hide the background of the progress showing only the progress part where it changes depending on the progress level. let's say 20 below is green 40 below is yellow 60 below  is orange and red for 60 up like the typical audio levels we see in media players. But I don't know why I can't even set the background of my progress bar into transparent as well as changing my progressDrawable changes the whole progressbar in my case. Need some help for this. Anyway here's the screenshot and XML:

```
<ProgressBar
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/mic_level"
                android:indeterminate="false"
                android:layout_below="@+id/chk_Record"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:progress="50"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:progressDrawable="@color/holo_bright_blue"
                android:background="@color/transparent"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a drawable for your progress bars, like below. This is a very rough guide I have taken from one of my projects, so you probably (almost certainly) do not need gradients, but it should give you a rough idea at least.

Below makes the background transparent for a progress bar and changes the fore-colour to green.

Place this in the drawable folder, name is progress_styles.xml and now in the progressbar set:

```
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_styles"
```

```
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="5dip" />

        <gradient
            android:startColor="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
           <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#00ff00" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#00ff00" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks! will try this out tomorrow. Well actually I already have the idea of using something similar to this one but well I'm just also curious and wondering why does changing the properties manually gives me different result as I expected. This part is somewhat troublesome since I can't tell if my ideas will work or not.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mark as correct answer. Anyway this helps me. What I've done is created 4 xml for this with the color scheme I mentioned. Then programatically applied it based on the amplitude level. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Gradient angle can help to vary color on change of progress bar state.

You have to create custom xml for that with `layer` and add `item` to it like...

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:id="@android:id/background">  //---this is progress background
 </item>
 ...
 <item android:id="@android:id/progress">   //----this is progress status
 </item>
</layer-list>
```

[Check my this answer for detail, if it could help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20892622/2553431)