# How to change progress bar fore color?

Tags: android

I want to change progress bar default(yellow) color to green color.Please help me

Comment: Have a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020882/how-to-change-progress-bars-progress-color-in-android

Answer (score 2):

Use in xml:

```
android:progressTint="@color/cb_background"
```

Comment: Available only from api level 21