# Making A Custom Skinny ProgressBar / Seekbar

Tags: android, seekbar

At a high level, I have done several types of progress bar styles, but they are all ugly when I have attempted to make them skinny.

I am looking for a jump start tutorial or layout that will give a bar that looks similar to below image

[image]

Any ideas?  I will be glad to publish the results when/if I get them working.

Comment: Did you try setting progress drawable and thumb?

Comment: Well, yes.  That's what has to be done no matter what.  I am more so looking for examples or work or tutorials on how to make a skinny progress bar.

Comment: You will find a very good tutorial [here](http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/02/create-a-custom-styled-ui-slider-seekbar-in-android/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I have used the tutorial before.  I am specifically looking for one that uses a skinny seekbar like the image posted.  Thanks again.

Comment: I dont see any big difference. Should suffice ur needs. Just a matter of modifying the xml  n drawables.

Comment: Did you make your asset into a 9-patch?  The view system will automatically handle resizing.  That's how buttons, etc. are done, and we have excellent results 9-patching borders and the like.

Comment: I tried making 9 patch images, but failed miserably.  I got it to work with a small thumb, rather than a nice oversized one.  I would like to revisit this in the future though.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is a property android:maxHeight which does exactly what you need. You should set the android:thumb drawable bigger than the maxHeight to achieve the slick seekbar effect.

For example:

```
  <SeekBar
      android:id="@+id/whiteBalanceSeek"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
      android:max="200"
      android:maxHeight="3dp"
      android:paddingLeft="10dp"
      android:paddingRight="10dp"
      android:progress="100"
      android:progressDrawable="@drawable/slider_progress"
      android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_img" />
```

The slider_progress drawable was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020882/how-to-change-progress-bars-progress-color-in-android) and the thumb_img is a bare PNG with a red circle.

Here is what I got:

[image: Slick sliders]

Comment: can you share slider_progress and thumb_img, i think the key is the progressDrawable and thumb

Comment: the progressDrawable is nothing special. I have reused the XML from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020882/how-to-change-progress-bars-progress-color-in-android

And the thumb image is a bare red circle PNG

Comment: I have a doubt... Isn't `maxHeight` supposed to be the height of the whole `SeekBar` and hence cut off even the thumb in case it exceeds it? Why does it only work for the progressBar?

Comment: @VeneetReddy That is because `maxHeight` belongs to the SeekBar's superclass: ProgressBar, hence meaning the height of the line, excluding the thumb. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#attr_android:maxHeight