# Programmatically add background images to android seekbar

Tags: android

I want to add background images to my seekbar through java code not through xml. I want my seekbar to look like below image.

http://imageshack.us/a/img32/3834/sliderbar.png

My seekbar is also created through java code only not using any xml file.

I dont want to refer any xml file to do this, everything should be done through code.!

Can somebody help to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I created xml drawable files in drawable-hdpi folder called progress.xml and thumb.xml and referred them in seekbar.xml of layout folder

Comment: and so i don't understand your question

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setThumb`,`setProgressDrawable` or `setBackground` methods of your `SeekBar`! If you really want a cool customized seekbar like [this](http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/02/create-a-custom-styled-ui-slider-seekbar-in-android/), I suggest you try referring xml files. It would make your life easier.

I've wrote a simple example that will give you a start point.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);//the layout that has your seekbar

        SeekBar mSeekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);//your seek bar

        mSeekBar.setThumb(R.drawable.thumb_image);//your thumb image
        mSeekBar.setProgressDrawable(R.drawable.progress_image);//your progress image
        mSeekBar.setBackground(R.drawable.background_image);//your background image
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried refering to xml files but was always getting ResourceNotFoundException, i could not get rid of this even after cleaning and rebuilding my project hundreds of times.There were no errors in my xml files. Basically i want to avoid hardcoding through xml.

Comment: I want seekbar to look exactly like in the image above, this code doesnt give me that.

Comment: The example is just the IDEA of the solution according to your question. Perhaps you could change the parameters according to the xml files of your project...

Comment: Is there any way to do progrmmatically what we generally do through xml files in this case? I mean defining layerlist drawables by java code.

Comment: Of course! You can instantiate your `View` and set the parameters, one by one, in the same way like the example above.

Comment: Above code resulted in this :  http://imageshack.us/a/img202/8252/sliderib.png  only thumb looks fine, i think backgroundDrawable is overwritten by progressDrawable. green image is filled entire seekbar.

Comment: Check out this link. It might helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056803/making-a-custom-skinny-progressbar-seekbar

Answer (score 0):

Try this for seekbar clip

```
Drawable thumb = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.mipmap.cir_32);
mSeekBar.setThumb(thumb);
```