# How to create custom seekbar and do optimization?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, custom-view, android-seekbar

I try create a custom seekbar like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/8B0Q8.png

But i encountered problem this problems : https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcQG7.png

I use this project for dynamically change text : github.com/Amit-Gupta26/AndroidCustomSeekBar

My layout code is here:

```
 <RelativeLayout
 android:id="@+id/layout_seekbar"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="0dp"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:background="@drawable/seekbar_bg" >

 <SeekBar
     android:id="@+id/seekbar"
     style="@style/CustomSeekBar"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

I try many different methods. But i couldnt achieve stability on all screens. 
How can  do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this post will help you:

[Custom Seekbar](http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/02/create-a-custom-styled-ui-slider-seekbar-in-android/)

Also you need to use 9patch images

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the problems you faced, I believe that your problem is NOT how to create a customized seekbar, but how to control thumb size and bar size each alone, like making the thimb much bigger without having to make the bar or the endings that big, I see that you must have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18559778/1638739) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056803/making-a-custom-skinny-progressbar-seekbar/) and [here](http://www.yogeshblogspot.com/how-to-create-custom-seekbar-custom-seekbar-example)