# Editing framework-res.apk

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

Screenshot :

[image]

How do I change that yellow color to blue or another color? Should I edit or add any xml file in framework-res.apk? I want to change the yellow color to cyan.

Comment: Is that progress bar part of a system app, or your app?

Comment: That is the progress bar of system app..

Comment: You can find the code of that system app in the android repository, then check among its xml files how they did that slider, there might be a reference to some color resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer the following link:

http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/02/create-a-custom-styled-ui-slider-seekbar-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

SeekBar uses a drawable for this. I would say the preferred drawable is a xml defined shape but I guess one could use an image too.

See this question - to which this question could be considered duplicate:

[How to change progress bar's progress color in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020882/how-to-change-progress-bars-progress-color-in-android)