# Changing the colors in progressbar

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using a progressbar, yet it appears to be all in white. When I used the same code on a previous project, I got a black background and it looked perfect. How can I change it so that the background is black again. I use this code to launch the progressbar

```
   ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Searching...", true);
```

Do I need to set something in my xml file for this screen?

Comment: This thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020882/how-to-change-progress-bars-progress-color-in-android should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that your current app is using the Holo Light theme, and that your previous app used Holo Dark. You can see examples of progress bars in both [here](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/progress.html).

You can change your app's theme to Holo Dark by adding the following to your manifest's `<application>` tag:
`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dark"`.
The Android Developer pages contain more information on themes [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).