# Color changing in Custom Progress Wheel at runtime in android programmatically

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I am doing for custom circular progress wheel. here what i need for, once the progress wheel finish it hundred percent progress. then , when i click again,i need to change the progressing color at runtime...

I downloaded code from this link..
https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel

note : I click on a button, the progress starts progressing. that progress bar circle already one color. After the progress complete 100%, I want it to start again, that time , i need to change the color to be red runtimely...

I tried this link also.. this link is for having for default progress bar. 
but, i am using for custom progress bar.thats why, i cant used this method like... 
http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.in/2012/11/android-change-indeterminate-progress.html
http://www.tiemenschut.com/how-to-customize-android-progress-bars/

can anyone help me to complete this task..
Thanks Advance....

my code :
     onCreate Method:

```
increment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@SuppressLint("WrongCall")
public void onClick(View v) {
Log.v("test", "-----increment button clicked--------");
if(!running) {
progress1 = (int) 370 ; 
Thread s = new Thread(r);
s.start();
}
}
});

final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @SuppressLint("WrongCall")
        public void run() {
            //Log.v("test", "----- thread called--------");
            running = true;
            //Log.v("test", "progress:"+progress);
            //Log.v("test", "progress1:"+progress1);
            progress2 = progress - progress1 ;   
                          //progress = 360 , progress1 = uservalue
            Log.v("test", "progress:"+progress);
            Log.v("test", "progress1:"+progress1);
            Log.v("test", "progress2 = progress - progress1:"+progress2);
            //percentage = pw_two.incrementProgress();
            // pw_two.setBarColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));

            while(progress2<360) {    
            percentage = pw_two.incrementProgress();
            Log.v("test","percentage:"+percentage);
                progress2++;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(15);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



 // here when crossing 360 above , then color change effect needed..
 //why we using this function, when put ten minutes for break,
    who taking more than ten minutes,, 
 // then that time itself, need to change color..
   i finish that time calculation....
                if(progress2 > 359) {
// here.. need to call this method two times.. then only, wheel will be refreshed......
                    //onPause_Reset_ProgressWheelOne();
                    onPause_Reset_ProgressWheelOne();
                    //break;
                }
            }

            running = false;
        }
     };

  public void onPause_Reset_ProgressWheelOne() {

     Log.v("test", "onPause_Reset_ProgressWheelOne--------");

    progress = 360;
    pw_two.setRimColor(Color.parseColor("#fe854c")); //1988c4   //fe854c
    pw_two.setBarColor(Color.RED);
    //pw_two.resetCount();  
    pw_two.refreshWheel();
    // progress = 0;
    // pw_two.setProgress(0);

  }

 ProgressWheel.java CLass  :

  public void refreshWheel() {

    setupPaints();
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you tell me how you reference this library in your project? Did you set this ProgressBar project as a library, and reference it in your project like that?

Comment: Hi, i did not include as a library. i just copy that class files into my existing project folders. and used it.. same for xml files to layout,where ever you want..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside `ProgressWheel.java` (com.todddavies.components.progressbar.ProgressWheel), add a method:

```
public void refreshTheWheel() {

    setupPaints();

}
```

> I click on a button, the progress starts progressing. that progress bar circle already one color. After the progress complete 100%, I want it to start again, that time , i need to change the color to be red runtimely

When you need to change the color:

```
// Progress is 100%
if (progress == 360) {

    // Change the color
    mProgressWheel.setBarColor(Color.RED);

    // Refresh
    mProgressWheel.refreshTheWheel();

    // Reset progress
    progress = 0;
    mProgressWheel.setProgress(0);

    // You can also use:
    // mProgressWheel.resetCount();
}
```

Note: Please make sure that editing/adding to this library is allowed.

**Edit:**

See if the following changes get you the desired output:

Declare global variables:

```
// `progress` isn't needed
// int progress = 360;
int progress1 = 0;
int progress2 = 0;

....
....

increment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Log.v("test", "-----increment button clicked--------");

        if(!running) {

            // I am not sure what you are using `progress1` for
            // progress1 = (int) 370 ;

            progress1 = 0;
            progress2 = 0;

            // reset `pw_two`
            pw_two.resetCount();

            Thread s = new Thread(r);
            s.start();
        }
    }
});
```

Now, the `Runnable`:

```
final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        running = true;

        // I could not figure out why you are using this
        // Can you explain what this does?
        // progress2 = progress - progress1 ;

        while(progress2 < 361) {
            pw_two.incrementProgress();

            // Increment both `progress1` and `progress2`
            progress2++;
            progress1++;        

            try {
                Thread.sleep(15);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Here, reset `progress2`, but not `progress1`
            if (progress2 == 360) {
                pw_two.setRimColor(Color.parseColor("#fe854c")); //1988c4   //fe854c
                pw_two.setBarColor(Color.RED);
                pw_two.refreshWheel();
                progress2 = 0;
                pw_two.setProgress(0);

                // Log value of `progress1`
                Log.v("Progress 1", "progress1 is " + progress1);
            }
        }
        running = false;
    }
};
```

You do not need to call another method. At `progressValue = 360`, the color will switch. If I somehow misunderstood what you are trying to achieve, could you explain with some use-cases?

Comment: thank you for reply..its working fine, but, i need to call the refreshwheel method for two time.. then only its working..

Comment: but, now i have one problem, i need to change the color when continuously after reached 360. i dont want to click again.prev background color is same. how much percentage crossed above 360, that state only need to change the new color..

Comment: @harikrishnan You are welcome. Can you post your activity's code in the question above? I tried this on my end and it was working fine. In fact, I did not even implement the `onClick()` functionality. I simply started the `ProgressWheel` once, and immediately after it crossed `100 %`, the color switched to red. A look at your code will give me a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: @harikrishnan Please check my edit above. Let me know if something is unclear or wrong.

Comment: thank you for your reply..but, one small misunderstand.. here, 
progress2 = progress - progress1 ; // this is for executing the while loop process..progress = 360 ,progress1 = 370 (user giving value when button click).

Comment: why i given 370 for, that loop will execute 370 time, at that time, when crossing 360, that time need to change the color with remainig 10 progress need to show red color,(here progress1 and progressValue is same).

Comment: @harikrishnan Let's continue our talk here: [Link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36640/color-changing-in-custom-progress-wheel-at-runtime-in-android-programmatically).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36665/discussion-between-harikrishnan-and-user2558882)

Comment: @Vikram Hi, I am also using same library. Can you please tell me how can I manipulate the timing of the ProgressBar.

Comment: @harikrishnan  have used ur code but its not changing color

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://github.com/strider2023/Radial-Menu-Widget-Android/blob/master/src/com/touchmenotapps/radialdemo/RadialProgressActivity.java) example, it have a circular progress bar that change color when progress increased.