# Progress Activity Circle between Activity calls

Tags: android

On Click of sign up goes to login page. I want to display a Progress Circle in between. I have seen examples in stack overflow explaining this with AsynTasks, for ListView's and all. I want a very simple example of displaying it by giving a delay time on click of Sign Up Button when it loads my login screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/layout_padding" >

    <!-- To remove the focus of edit text for the first time -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/title_image_height"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/title_image_margin_top"
        android:contentDescription="@string/title"
        android:src="@drawable/site_image" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editWorkEmail"
        style="@style/text.edit"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin"
        android:hint="@string/hint_work_email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSignUp"
        style="@style/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/editWorkEmail"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin"
        android:text="@string/button_sign_up" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress" >

    </ProgressBar>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503718/color-changing-in-custom-progress-wheel-at-runtime-in-android-programmatically/18567536#18567536  for circular progress bar

Answer (score 1):

First of all when you start activity then I think it start immediately and don't take too much time to start don't know how you actually doing your job. You can display progress dialog when calling your request and wait for the response once you getting the response just dismiss the current progress and if the response was successful sign up process then just start login

For using AsynTask class you can do like this way

```
private class SignupTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{
     private ProgressDialog pDialog;
     public void onPreExecute(){
         pDialog = ProgressDialog.showDialog(context,"Signup Process","Please wait");
     }
     public String doInBackground(Void... params){
         // here call your web call process and send appropriate message as return
     }
     public void onPostExecute(String result){
         // here get the result do action
         pDialog.dismiss();
     }
}
```

create object of this class and execute `new SignupTask().execute();`