# Android change progressbar color dynamically

Tags: android, colors

How I set the color of ProgressBar from SQLite Int value?
this code does not work for me.

```
myProgressB.setProgressColor(cb.color);
```

Comment: this question has been asked and answered many times before. Please use google or the search on this site.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020882/how-to-change-progress-bars-progress-color-in-android

Answer (score 1):

You have to change it on update from another thread. I typically do this via an AsyncTask thread where I would override the onProgressUpdate as you download a file or do some other work

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     int count = urls.length;
     long totalSize = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
         publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
         // Escape early if cancel() is called
         if (isCancelled()) break;
     }
     return totalSize;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
```

// your work here

```
     myProgressB.setProgressColor(cb.color);



 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
 }
```

}