# An alternative way to set color values than in the drawable XML

Tags: java, android, xml-drawable

I have a customized ProgressBar which gets its drawable from the drawable folder.

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="5dip" />
        <gradient
                android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d"
                android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#ff747674"
                android:angle="270"
        />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="#80ffd300"
                    android:centerColor="#80ffb600"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#a0ffcb00"
                    android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@android:id/progress"
>
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners
                android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#33FF33"
                android:endColor="#008000"
                android:angle="270" />
         </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

I want to be able to change the startColor of progress (which is "#33FF33" in the XML). I need an alternative way to set the color.

lg, couka

Comment: Are you looking for a way to change the color in your Android program, or how to find the color value you want to change in the XML?

Comment: @ErstwhileIII - Looks like they want to change the startColor dynamically after compile time.

Comment: @RudiKershaw you can do that, see GradientDrawable.setColors

Answer (score 0):

After this line ,your ProgressBar will be in **`RED`** color: you can change it as you want

```
progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED, Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Or try this solution :
**https://stackoverflow.com/a/11288434/2337837**

Comment: Just realised this doesn't fix their problem either because they need to set the start colour of a gradient, not the whole colour.