# how to change progress bar color progrramically

Tags: android

im using this sample code for signal info http://code.google.com/p/krvarma-android-samples/source/browse/trunk/PhoneStateSample/src/com/varma/samples/phonestatesample/PhoneStateSample.java which show signal strength in progressbar below is my code which piece of cdoe i took from that sample class my question is how i will change color of progressbar which create programiclaly?

```
                private void setSignalLevel(int id,int infoid,int level){
            int progress = (int) ((((float)level)/31.0) * 100);
            String signalLevelString = getSignalLevelString(progress);

            ((ProgressBar)findViewById(id)).setProgress(progress);

            ((TextView)findViewById(infoid)).setText(signalLevelString);

            Log.i("signalLevel ","" + progress);
    }
```

Comment: Go to this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020882/how-to-change-progress-bars-progress-color-in-android?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020882/how-to-change-progress-bars-progress-color-in-android?rq=1)

Comment: im not using xml for progressbar

Comment: @user3456519 do you know what Drawable class is for? if so try to call setProgressDrawable with your own custom Drawable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
yourProgressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED, Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

in your case:

```
((ProgressBar)findViewById(id)).getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED, Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Comment: i dont know the name of my progressbar  seee this ecxample i folllow this http://code.google.com/p/krvarma-android-samples/source/browse/trunk/PhoneStateSample/src/com/varma/samples/phonestatesample/PhoneStateSample.java

Comment: for your case i have added the code...

Comment: ok thanx but tell me only 1 help more in example code which i used its check battery level at this line 
  if(level > EXCELLENT_LEVEL)             signalLevelString = "Excellent";  how i wil change color of progressbar at that stage???

Comment: write same line of code inside this if (level > EXCELLENT_LEVEL) condition and some different color..

Comment: ur code mode.Multiply will show double effect