# Seekbar Progress image issue

Tags: android, seekbar

I am trying to implement a seekbar , which has different progress color to signify the progress

What i want to implement is like this

[image]

but what i am ending up with is this

[image]

as you can see the progress **light blue color img is not coming over the darkblue color line** img

both of these are png images

[image]
[image]

XML for seekbar

```
 <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/custom_seekBar"
        android:layout_width="365dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-12dp"
        android:max="100"
        android:paddingLeft="7dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_background_selector"
        android:thumb="@drawable/slider_button" />
```

android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_background_selector" referes this xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/normal_slider_bg"/>
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <scale
            android:drawable="@drawable/normal_slider_bg"
            android:scaleWidth="100%" />
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <scale
            android:drawable="@drawable/selected_slider_bg"
            android:scaleWidth="100%" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: If you got solution share here.Else put your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.setProgressDrawable` to change the color {[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2021119/1083093)}

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="5dip" />
        <gradient
                android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d"
                android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#ff747674"
                android:angle="270"
        />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="#80ffd300"
                    android:centerColor="#80ffb600"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#a0ffcb00"
                    android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@android:id/progress"
>
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners
                android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/progress_start"
                android:endColor="@color/progress_end"
                android:angle="270" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

---

### [Also Check this Link](http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/02/create-a-custom-styled-ui-slider-seekbar-in-android/)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LSeekBar extends SeekBar {

     public LSeekBar (Context context) {
            super(context);
            Initialise();
        }
        public LSeekBar (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            Initialise();
        }
        public LSeekBar (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            Initialise();
        }
        private void Initialise(){
            this.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.seek_bar_background));
        }

}
```

---->seek_bar_background(make in drawable)

```
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <nine-patch
        android:src="@drawable/progress_cyan"
        >
    </nine-patch>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item>
            <clip>
                <bitmap
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:src="@drawable/progress_red"
                    />
            </clip>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
```

normal_slider_bg it should be nine-patch.in your case.

======>SeekBar as

```
                   <com.TestView.views.LSeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:maxHeight="6dip"
                    android:minHeight="6dip"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:thumb="@drawable/thumbler_small" 
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton2"/>
```