# Lollipop - Indeterminate ProgressBar color change - Programmatically

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-5.0-lollipop

I am using the code below to change the color of Indeterminate ProgressBar. This works well, till KitKat. But on Lollipop, it just stays Green. Can anyone help me out with this. I want to do it through Java and not XML.

Code: This sets the spinner color to pink

```
pd.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(0xFFeA6060,
                    android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15809803/1761003)

Comment: I am using an indeterminate progressbar and i get a NPE if i use a getProgressDrawable() on it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're using `multiply` which means that you will change to a color depending on the current color (which is green):

[image]

Try using `android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP` for example.

If want to use the real color that you provided then use `PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN`

Comment: This picture is truly worth 1000 words. Thank you