# can not override the ProgressBar style in project from library project

Tags: android, android-styles, android-progressbar

I have written the style for progress bar in the lib and now wanted to change the color of progress bar in main project for customization.

lib style

```
<style name="progressBar" parent="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/progress</item>
</style>
```

main style

```
 <style name="progressBarOC" parent="@style/progressBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/progress</item>
</style>
```

style for the v21

```
    <style name="progressBarOC" parent="@style/progressBar">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/theme_color</item>
</style>
```

progress.xml

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="1080">
<shape android:shape="ring" android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
    android:thicknessRatio="15" android:useLevel="false">
    <size android:width="60dip" android:height="60dip" />
    <gradient android:type="sweep" android:useLevel="false"
        android:startColor="@color/theme_color"
        android:endColor="@color/translucent_100"
        android:angle="0"
        />
</shape>
```

Comment: put color in progress.xml

Comment: @KrishnaJ already added it

Comment: Change your theme_color and translucent_100 colors

Comment: but it only affected on pre lollipop version what about the lollipop and more

Comment: you can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020882/how-to-change-progress-bars-progress-color-in-android