# Change Horizontal Progress Bar Color

Tags: android, styles, progress-bar

### Problem Description

I'm trying to change `ProgressBar` color using custom style defined in the `style.xml`

#### layout.xml

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="@style/ProgressTheme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateBehavior="repeat" />
```

#### style.xml

```
<style name="ProgressTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
        <item name="colorAccent">#000</item>
</style>
```

#### Question

I find some useful articles about how to change color programatically or by adding some `layer-list`, but I want simple solution. And I guess that the way how I implemented should work.

How I can change color?

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020882/how-to-change-progress-bars-progress-color-in-android

Comment: @nicopasso it's not a duplicate, as I need specific solution, I need to know is there a way to do this direct from style.xml

Comment: Your question is "How I can change color?". There already plenty of answers to that. As a side note the theme solution works only for API Level >= 21

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

you can try using:

```
mProgressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.BLACK, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

For lollipop and above,use:

```
mProgressBar.setProgressTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.BLACK));
```

If looking for xml solution, try these properties of `ProgressBar` (Api 21 +):

```
android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"
android:indeterminateTint="@android:color/black"
```

Create the below `<style.../>` in `styles.xml(v21)` works on Api 21+:

```
<style name="blackProgressBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:indeterminateTintMode">src_atop</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateTint">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

And apply it as:

```
<ProgressBar
    ...
    style="@style/blackProgressBar" />
```

Comment: I need solution using style only (I mentioned in my question).

Answer (score 0):

You can style your progress dialog this way: create a drawable file with your ring shape (circular_progress_dialog.xml)

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="270"
android:toDegrees="270">
<shape
    android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="2dp"
    android:useLevel="true"><!-- this line fixes the issue for lollipop api 21 -->

    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="@color/main_background"
        android:startColor="@color/main_orange"
        android:type="sweep"
        android:useLevel="false" />
</shape>
</rotate>
```

one to style your progress bar

```
 <style name="ProgressBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar">
    <item name="android:layout_centerHorizontal">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerVertical">true</item>
    <item name="android:visibility">gone</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/transparency_pleca</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/circular_progress_dialog</item>
</style>
```

Notice your "android:indeterminateDrawable" property

Yout can create an instance of ProgressDialog and add your style with

```
// create progressDialog
final ProgressDialog myProgressDialog = new  ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this);
myProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(R.style.ProgressBar)
myProgressDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be late, but I am putting this here for anyone else who might run into the same issue.

In your `styles.xml` file, add a new style for your Progress Bar

```
<style name="CustomProgressBarTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/myProgressBarColor</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal</item>
</style>
```

The `android:progressBarStyle` attribute ensures the Progress Bar is horizontal.

And just add this style to your progress bar, and set `android:indeterminate="true"`.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:theme="@style/slang_lib_ProgressBarTheme" />
```

**NOTE: Using `style` attribute would not work here, use `android:theme` instead.**

Answer (score 0):

You need add android:indeterminateTint="@color/red"