# Progress bar colour change in android for all api levels

Tags: android, android-progressbar

kindly help me i want to change color of my progress bar i am using

```
mProgress.setProgressTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#FF5201")));
```

but this is not working below 21 level kindly send me a solution thanks

Comment: go through the link [change progress bars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020882/how-to-change-progress-bars-progress-color-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this**

```
  progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(
    getResources().getColor(Your_Color),
    android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

**and replace Your_Color with the desired color like: R.color.your_color_code**
*i hope this is work for you*

Comment: thnxs,i tried this but when i applied this i didnt show any color ion progress bar