# Change default progress bar color using xml

Tags: android

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loader"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WhiteAccent"
        />

<style name="AppTheme.WhiteAccent" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/green</item>
</style>
```

Progressbar loader color is blueish. I want to change it to green. This is not working. What's wrong and why?

Comment: try it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020882/how-to-change-progress-bars-progress-color-in-android