# Cannot change color of progress bar?

Tags: android, progress-bar

Created own color in ***color.xml*** `<color name="colorProgressBar">#006600</color>`

In ***styles.xml***

```
<style name="ProgressBarde">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorProgressBar</item>
    </style>
```

and added this to the main **.xml** activity

```
<ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:theme="@style/ProgressBarde" />
```

As you can the I choosed green color for my progress bar. It's even changed to my  android studio [editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jOv6.png). But when run it on my real android device by usb It's not changing. Where is my mistake?

Comment: your xml is correct. i copy-pasted it and i am able to see green colour progress bar.

Comment: Try this [link](
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020882/how-to-change-progress-bars-progress-color-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running your app on a pre-Lollipop device? On these devices the Material-themed progress bars are not available. instead, they are replaced with the default Holo progress bar. You can try using a third-party library for this.

(This should have been a comment, but my reputation is too low.)

Comment: I am running on Samsung Galaxy s4

Comment: I mean what's your Android version? If it is below 5.0, then you could try using a library; if it's 5.0 or higher, then my answer is wrong and the bug lies somewhere else.

Also, instead of using a library, try applying a tint to the progress bar on pre-lollipop devices: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15809803/6244733. It won't look material but it's close enough.

Comment: I have 4.2.2 ..then I'll try to test higher than 5.0 version