# How can I modify all of a ProgressBar?

Tags: java, android

I'm able to modify the height, width, and outer color of a ProgessBar widget.  But that doesn't seem to affect the inner part of the bar.  The red line that progresses.  Is there a way to modify that? Or do I need to create a custom widget for that?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change progress bar's progress color in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020882/how-to-change-progress-bars-progress-color-in-android)

Comment: What is your target? modify height of that red portion or change the color of that portion?

Comment: @Sagar Both!  And I can't find how to?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `android:indeterminateTint="@color/green"` in your xml.

You can also try `setIndeterminateDrawable(drawable)` or `setIndeterminateTintList()` (I didn't check this solution)

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the height of the progress indicator, it can be achieved by adding following parameter in your layout.xml for ProgressBar:

`android:scaleY="5"`

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleY="5"
         />
```

If you want to reduce the padding around the indicator, then modify `layout_height` attribute as follows:

```
 <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp" 
             />
```

You can use following on version older than Lollipop to change the indicator's color:

```
progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(
    Color.RED, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

For Lollipop and above, use following:

`progressBar.setProgressTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED));`

You can refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020882/how-to-change-progress-bars-progress-color-in-android) for progressBar color

Comment: Hello, The scale does work but it increases the entire bar (background and the progress indicator.)  What if I wanted less background?  Like just the progress bar?

Comment: You mean, you just want to increase the height of progress bar without impacting the indicator?